# timeout hover delay on hover different div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make the first square box onhover, then show the bigger box a little bit delay then when I move the mouse hover the big box, the big box still appears.However, my code works incorrectly.

If someone could please help me out? Thanks

Sample http://jsfiddle.net/9oLs3fyh/

```
    var timeout;
$("#box1").hover(function () {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    $("#box2").delay(500).show();
}, function () {
    timeout = setTimeout(function(){
      $("#box2").delay(500).hide();
    },500);
});

if($("#box2").is(':hover')){
$("#box2").show();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try assiging class `hovered` (check the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9oLs3fyh/4/)):

CSS

```
.hovered { display:block }
```

On mouseenter of `#accountIcon` assign class `hovered` on `#accountPopup` element.

Then, on mouseleave, if the target element (`#accountPopup`) is not visisble, just remove the class.

```
$('#accountIcon').on('mouseenter', function() {
    $('#accountPopup').addClass('hovered');
}).on('mouseleave', function() {
    var target = $('#accountPopup');
    if (!target.is(':visible')) {
        target.removeClass('hovered');
    }
});
$('#accountPopup').on('mouseleave', function() {
    $(this).removeClass('hovered');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var timeout;
$("#accountIcon").hover(function () {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    $("#accountPopup").delay(500).show(500);
}, function () {
    setTimeout(function(){
      $("#accountPopup").delay(500).hide(500);
    },500);
});

if($("#accountPopup").is(':hover')){
$("#accountPopup").show();
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9oLs3fyh/1/)

I think this is a good way to achieve that by wrap your divs inside one div

```
<div class="conatiner">
    <div id="accountIcon"></div>
     <div id="accountPopup"></div>
</div>

.conatiner{
    overflow:hidden;
}


var timeout;
$(".conatiner").hover(function () {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    $("#accountPopup").delay(500).show(500);
}, function () {
    setTimeout(function(){
      $("#accountPopup").delay(500).hide(500);
    },500);
});
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/9oLs3fyh/3/)

and while you use hover .. you can just use css with visibility and transition delay

```
<div class="conatiner">
    <div id="accountIcon"></div>
     <div id="accountPopup"></div>
</div>


.conatiner:hover #accountPopup{
   display: block;
   -webkit-transition-delay: 1s; /* Safari */
   transition-delay: 1s;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/9oLs3fyh/7/)